# Как восстановить $PATH в командной оболочке zsh (Mac OS)

Tags: mysql, консоль, macos, mac, zsh

помогите восстановить $PATH в терминале Mac OS.
Произошло после того, как я пытался добавить path для вызова mysql
с помощью такой команды

```
export PATH=${PATH}:/usr/local/mysql/bin/
```

и теперь при входе выдаёт это

```
Last login: Mon May 31 20:11:46 on console
/Users/OlimpicBoy/.zprofile:source:1: no such file or directory: /Users/OlimpicBoy/.profile
```

Командная оболочка Zsh, не могу найти ни один из профилей
.bashrc или .bash_profile/ .bash_login/ .profile .zprofile
Где они находятся чтобы их поменять вручную, через поиск искал и не нашел ничего, по-видимому нужно добавить один из них, но я не знаю куда и что должно находиться в файле(

Comment: Даже не успел познакомиться с Веб-разработкой, а уже все сломалось))
Помогите плз)

Если нужны, какие-нибудь логи, скажите пожалуйста где они находятся ахах, я вам все скину))
Искал инфу в гугле, везде перевод англоязычных вопросов, но переведено так криво, что я ничего не понял)) Все команды изменены из-за перевода, а источник не работает, будь оно неладно)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Наберите в консоли

```
touch /Users/OlimpicBoy/.profile
```

Эта команда создаст пустой файл `/Users/OlimpicBoy/.profile`, и ваш `.zprofile` перестанет ругатся на отсутствующий файл.

Comment: так просто?))) А что так можно было?)) Вы лучший просто, мой бро)
А подскажите пожалуйста, я правильно прописал путь для mysql? 
У меня есть ощущение что, я что-то сделал не правильно